# QGIS not working with Python installation on Wily 15.10: broken paths/dependencies

Tags: apt, python, dpkg, dependencies, qgis

When I try to run QGIS, I get the following errors at startup:

```
An error occured during execution of following code:
import pyplugin_installer


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qgis/utils.py", line 572, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
ImportError: No module named pyplugin_installer


Python version:
2.7.10 (default, Oct 14 2015, 16:09:02) 
[GCC 5.2.1 20151010]

QGIS version:
2.12.1-Lyon 'Lyon', exported

Python path:
['/usr/share/qgis/python', u'/home/jesse/.qgis2/python', u'/home/jesse/.qgis2/python/plugins', '/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/home/jesse/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wx-3.0-gtk2', u'/home/jesse/.qgis2//python']


##################################


An error occured during execution of following code:
pyplugin_installer.initPluginInstaller()


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
NameError: name 'pyplugin_installer' is not defined


Python version:
2.7.10 (default, Oct 14 2015, 16:09:02) 
[GCC 5.2.1 20151010]

QGIS version:
2.12.1-Lyon 'Lyon', exported

Python path:
['/usr/share/qgis/python', u'/home/jesse/.qgis2/python', u'/home/jesse/.qgis2/python/plugins', '/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/home/jesse/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wx-3.0-gtk2', u'/home/jesse/.qgis2//python']
```

After this, QGIS starts up. I then get a similar error message when I try to open up the Python console or plugins menu.

I've tried `apt-get purge qgis` and then re-installing it with `apt-get install qgis -f`. But I get the following error messages when trying to purge/install:

```
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.4-1) ...
Setting up qgis-providers-common (1:2.12.1+git20151211+80c5cb6+23wily) ...
cp: cannot stat ‘/usr/share/qgis/resources/srs-template.db’: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package qgis-providers-common (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of qgis-providers:
 qgis-providers depends on qgis-providers-common (= 1:2.12.1+git20151211+80c5cb6+23wily); however:
  Package qgis-providers-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package qgis-providers (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 qgis-providers-common
 qgis-providers
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Obviously, the problem seems related to Python, but I can't figure out how to diagnose what is wrong here. Does anyone have any ideas about how to fix this, or ideas about other places to look for clues as to what is happening? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but it is working again now.

It was fixed in this update which I was able to install today:

http://hub.qgis.org/issues/13981